# How do I "glue" the sorted partition back to a sorted one? (Quick Sort Java Implementation)

Tags: java, debugging, sorting, quicksort

I have tested that my partitioning algorithm works well, but when it comes time in the implementation to make use of it, I get an array that is not sorted.  Since this is for a class, there's a certain I need to write the class itself so that I can return the answer as string. My problem is most likely in the qkSort() method. Here's the code:

```
private static int splitterElement;

public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(myMethod());
}

public static String myMethod() {
    String result = "";
    int[] testArray = null;
    testArray = populateArray(testArray, 7, 10);

    result += "Before sort: \n" + printArray(testArray);
    testArray = qkSort(testArray,1,testArray.length);
    result += "After sort: \n" + printArray(testArray);
    return result;
}

//Method to continually call the partition() method
public static int[] qkSort(int[] x, int left, int right){
    if (right - left >= 1) {
        //after running this method, the global variable splitterElement is assigned.
        x = partition(x,left,right);

        qkSort(x,left,splitterElement-1);
        qkSort(x,splitterElement + 1,right);
    }

    //base case. if right-left = 0, then the array length is 1, 
    //and that is already sorted
    return x;
}




/**
 * Populates an integer array with random integers. Should be used only with
 * non-itialized integer arrays. 
 * 
 * @param x an uninitialized array of integers and will be returned once it is populated.
 * @param sizeOfArray The size that array x will be initialized to.
 * @param rangeOfValues The range of values that that each element can be. This value should
 * not surpass the maximum value for integers, but no error-checking is performed. 
 * @return
 */
public static int[] populateArray (int[] x, int sizeOfArray, int rangeOfValues){
    x = new int[sizeOfArray];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        x[i] = (int)(Math.random() * rangeOfValues); //place a random number from 0 to rangeOfValues into array.
    }
    return x;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param x An integer array. It is assumed that x is initialized when the method is called.
 * @param left
 * @param right The length of the array can be used for the right int.
 * @see #populateArray(int[], int, int)
 * @return
 */
public static int[] partition (int[] x, int left, int right){
    //element of the splitter
    int l = (int) (Math.random() * x.length);
    splitterElement = l;
    x = swap (x,left,l);

    //value of the splitter
    int t = x[left];

    int i = left;
    for (int j = left + 1; j < right; j++){
        if (x[j] < t){
            i++;
            x = swap (x,i,j);
        }
    }
    x = swap(x,left,i);
    return x;
}

/**
 * Places the value at index1 in index2, and places the value at index2 in index1.
 * 
 * @param array The array that will be worked on.
 * @param index1 The first place we will switch values. 
 * @param index2 The second place we will switch values.
 * @return
 */
public static int[] swap (int[] array, int index1, int index2){
    int temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
    return array;
}

/**
 * A simple print method that prints an array.
 * @param array Input.
 */
public static String printArray (int[] array){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        result += array[i] + " ";
    }
    result += "\n";
    return result;
}
```

}

Output:

Before sort:
8 9 7 3 4 2 6

After sort:
8 6 3 9 7 2 4

Thanks for any ideas on what my problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues in your code:

1) the methods don't need to return the array, you could find a better use for the return value

2) using a global variable splitterElement doesn't work because its value can change during the first recursive call to qkSort. Method partition could return its value instead of returning the array, which is useless.

3) the first line of the partition method:

```
int l = (int) (Math.random() * x.length);
```

should be:

```
int l = left + (int) (Math.random() * (right - left));
```

because youre partitionning the range between left and right, not the whole array.

Comment: I see the idea in your 3rd point, but I'm a bit confused on points 1 and 2. You say that I could return something other than the int array, but if I don't return it, how can I save the modified array after the method has run? What's a better way to modify this array?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: An array is an object. Only a reference to the array is passed as an argument to a method.

Comment: To my understanding, Java does not pass a reference to the array when calling a method, it passes the value. It is a pass-by-value language (for both primitives and objects), not pass-by-reference. http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Comment: Reread the section "How does pass-by-value work with references?"

Comment: Ahah! Thinking of arrays as _objects_ helps a lot. Thanks for your help, Maurice!